# RecyclerView into ViewPager - How to change the appearance of elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewholder

I have a test application.

The questions is uploaded to ViewPager. Each Viewpager element is a fragment. On the fragment there is TextView for question text and RecyclerView for answer options.

I need a button to appear when I select the answer option for the main activity. When you click on the button, the answers should be highlighted in red or green.

I can not understand how to implement the latter. How can I change the colour of a RecyclerView item from Activity?

The code allows you to select one or more options and highlight them.
My java classes:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private QuestionViewModel viewModel;

private ViewPager questionsViewPager;
private TabLayout questionTabs;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView questionNumber;
private FloatingActionButton submitButton;
private OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener;

@Inject
ViewModelProviderFactory providerFactory;

@Inject
QuestionAdapter questionAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    questionsViewPager = findViewById(R.id.questionViewPager);
    questionTabs = findViewById(R.id.questionTabLayout);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.loadQuestionsProgressBar);
    questionNumber = findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
    submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitFloatingActionButton);
    onQuestionListener = questionAdapter;
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(QuestionViewModel.class);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Theme theme = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.THEME);
    int themeId = theme.getThemeId();

    initQuestionViewPager();
    subscribeObservers(themeId);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    navThemeScreen();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            navThemeScreen();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void subscribeObservers(int themeId) {
    viewModel.observeQuestions(themeId).observe(this, new Observer<Resource<List<Question>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Resource<List<Question>> listResource) {
            if (listResource != null) {
                switch (listResource.status) {
                    case LOADING:
                        showProgress(true);
                        break;
                    case SUCCESS:
                        questionAdapter.setQuestions(listResource.data);
                        initTabs();
                        questionNumber.setText("Вопрос 1 из " + listResource.data.size());
                        showProgress(false);
                        break;
                    case ERROR:
                        showProgress(false);
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, listResource.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initQuestionViewPager() {
    questionsViewPager.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
    questionsViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            questionNumber.setText("Вопрос " + Integer.toString(position + 1) + " из " + questionsViewPager.getAdapter().getCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

private void initTabs() {
    questionTabs.setupWithViewPager(questionsViewPager, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsViewPager.getAdapter().getCount(); ++i) {
        questionTabs.getTabAt(i).setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
    }
}

private void showProgress(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void navThemeScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ThemeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.submitFloatingActionButton:
            onQuestionListener.onSubmitClick(questionsViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }
}

public interface OnQuestionListener {
    void onSubmitClick(int questionNumber);
}
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, 
OptionViewHolder.OnOptionListener, QuestionActivity.OnQuestionListener {

private View view;
private TextView questionText;
private RecyclerView options;
private FloatingActionButton submitButton;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private SingleQuestionViewModel viewModel;
private int position;
private Question question;

@Inject
ViewModelProviderFactory providerFactory;

@Inject
OptionAdapter optionAdapter;

public static QuestionFragment newInstance(int position) {
    QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    position = getArguments().getInt("position");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
    questionText = view.findViewById(R.id.questionTextTextView);
    options = view.findViewById(R.id.optionsRecyclerView);
    submitButton = view.findViewById(R.id.submitFloatingActionButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(SingleQuestionViewModel.class);
    question = viewModel.getQuestion(position);

    initQuestion();
    initOptions();
}

private void initQuestion() {
    questionText.setText(question.getText());
}

private void initOptions() {
    if (question.isMultipleAnswer()) {
        optionAdapter.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    }
    optionAdapter.setOptions(question.getOptions());
    optionAdapter.setOnOptionListener(this);
    options.setAdapter(optionAdapter);
    options.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    options.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private void showSubmitButton(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        submitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.submitFloatingActionButton:
            boolean isCorrect = question.checkAnswers();
            int currPos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            new Handler().post(() -> viewPager.setCurrentItem(currPos + 1, true));
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onOptionSelected(OptionViewHolder v, SelectedOption selectedOption) {

}

@Override
public void onSubmitClick(int questionNumber) {
   RecyclerView.ViewHolder test = options.getChildViewHolder(options.getChildAt(0));
    optionAdapter.selectCorrectOptions();
}

class AnswerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        question.setAnswers(optionAdapter.getSelectedOptions());
        showSubmitButton(true);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**Page adapter**

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements QuestionActivity.OnQuestionListener {

private List<Question> questions;
private HashMap<Integer, WeakReference<Fragment>> fragments;
private QuestionActivity.OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener;

public QuestionAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    questions = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questions.size();
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
    fragments = new HashMap<>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment().newInstance(position);
    onQuestionListener = fragment;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    fragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onSubmitClick(int questionNumber) {
    onQuestionListener.onSubmitClick(questionNumber);
}
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdpater**

```
public class OptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OptionViewHolder> implements OptionViewHolder.OnOptionListener {

private List<SelectedOption> options;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private OptionViewHolder.OnOptionListener onOptionListener;
private boolean isMultiSelectionEnabled;
private HashMap<Integer, OptionViewHolder> holders;

public OptionAdapter() {
    options = new ArrayList<>();
    holders = new HashMap<>();
    isMultiSelectionEnabled = false;
}

public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
    this.options.clear();
    for(Option option : options) {
        this.options.add(new SelectedOption(option, false));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setOnOptionListener(OptionViewHolder.OnOptionListener onOptionListener) {
    this.onOptionListener = onOptionListener;
}

public void setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean multiSelectionEnabled) {
    isMultiSelectionEnabled = multiSelectionEnabled;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OptionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.option_item, parent, false);
    OptionViewHolder viewHolder = new OptionViewHolder(view, this);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OptionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SelectedOption selectedOption = options.get(position);
    holder.optionTextView.setText(selectedOption.getText());
    if (isMultiSelectionEnabled) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        holder.optionTextView.getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple, typedValue, true);
        int checkMarkDrawableResId = typedValue.resourceId;
        holder.optionTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(checkMarkDrawableResId);
    }
    else {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        holder.optionTextView.getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle, typedValue, true);
        int checkMarkDrawableResId = typedValue.resourceId;
        holder.optionTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(checkMarkDrawableResId);
    }

    holder.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    holder.setChecked(holder.selectedOption.isSelected());
    holders.put(position, holder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return options.size();
}

public List<Option> getSelectedOptions() {
    List<Option> selectedOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SelectedOption option : options) {
        if (option.isSelected()) {
            selectedOptions.add(option);
        }
    }

    return selectedOptions;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isMultiSelectionEnabled) {
        return OptionViewHolder.MULTI_SELECTION;
    }
    else {
        return OptionViewHolder.SINGLE_SELECTION;
    }
}

@Override
public void onOptionSelected(OptionViewHolder v, SelectedOption selectedOption) {
    if (!isMultiSelectionEnabled) {
        for (SelectedOption option : options) {
            if (!option.equals(selectedOption) && option.isSelected()) {
                option.setSelected(false);
            }
            else if (option.equals(selectedOption) && selectedOption.isSelected()) {
                option.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    onOptionListener.onOptionSelected(v, selectedOption);
}

public void selectCorrectOptions() {

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, OptionViewHolder> entry : holders.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().selectCorrectOptions();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public class OptionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final int SINGLE_SELECTION = 1;
public static final int MULTI_SELECTION = 2;
CheckedTextView optionTextView;
SelectedOption selectedOption;
OnOptionListener onOptionListener;

public OptionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnOptionListener onOptionListener) {
    super(itemView);
    this.onOptionListener = onOptionListener;
    optionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionTextView);
    optionTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (selectedOption.isSelected() && getItemViewType() == MULTI_SELECTION) {
        setChecked(false);
    }
    else {
        setChecked(true);
    }
    onOptionListener.onOptionSelected(this, selectedOption);
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    if (checked) {
        optionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66bfe8"));
    }
    else {
        optionTextView.setBackground(null);
    }
    selectedOption.setSelected(checked);
    optionTextView.setChecked(checked);
}

public void selectCorrectOptions() {
    if (selectedOption.isSelected() && selectedOption.isCorrect()) {
        optionTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#007f00"));
    }
    else {
        optionTextView.setBackground(null);
    }
    onOptionListener.onOptionSelected(this, selectedOption);
}

public interface OnOptionListener {

    void onOptionSelected(OptionViewHolder v, SelectedOption selectedOption);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to pass your item view to activity using interface. With your item view you can set background color or resource of your item.

So update your interface function with new parameter of type view and when you detect selection of item in your activity with interface, save the view reference and when the button is clicked, use that reference to set background.